# Correct way to add a working exposed filter (date) to a view displaying calendar entities

Tags: views

I'm using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 7.x-3.11, [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) 7.x-2.8, and [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) 7.x-3.4.  The view displays calendar entities in the calendar format with pagination.  When I add an exposed filter for month and year the view defaults back to the contextual filter; pagination works fine.

I've observed that when the pagination is used, the url is like: `/calendar?date=02-2015`.  When I use the exposed filter the url is like`/calendar?date_filter[value][month]=2&date_filter[value][year]=2015`.

I've considered using `hook_views_query_alter` but I'm not sure how to handle if there is switching between pagination and exposed filters.

Am I missing a configuration option?  If I do need to alter within code, what would be the best hook to do so within?

A paste of the view is here http://pastebin.com/WsxFze5z (page display).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, thanks; I hope that is more useful.

Comment: Great, now we have a real question! Thanks for the edit!